# Как сделать такую выборку sql?

Tags: php, sql

Делаю афишу(модуль dle 11.3) для сайта надо сделать выборку
Есть таблица с полем(диапазон дат формата Y-m-d) xfields по которому надо сделать выборку, надо выбрать новости в диапазон дат которых входит текущая дата + 14 дней

например так

```
$date_today = date("Y-m-d");

$sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM " . PREFIX . "_post  WHERE category = '$cat' AND '$date_today'  >= STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( xfields,  'date_from|', -1 ) ,  '||', 1 ), '%Y-%m-%d') AND '$date_today' <= STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( xfields,  'date_to|', -1 ) ,  '||', 1 ), '%Y-%m-%d') ");
```

я получу новости у которых дата начала раньше текущей, но дата окончания осле текущей,но не получу те у которых начало скажем завтра или послезавтра

а вот так я получу только те у которых будет начало

$date_today_unix - сегодняшняя дата в unix формате

$date_today_14_unix -сегодняшняя дата +14 дней в unix формате

```
$sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM " . PREFIX . "_post  WHERE category = '$cat' AND '$date_today_unix'  <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( xfields,  'date_from|', -1 ) ,  '||', 1 )) AND '$date_today_14_unix' >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( xfields,  'date_to|', -1 ) ,  '||', 1 )) ");
```

Пример поля xfields  `date_from|2017-05-20||date_to|2017-05-29` или `date_from|2017-05-27||date_to|2017-05-28`

Comment: Иными словами, есть интервал (сегодня .. сегодня + 2 недели), есть интервал (date_from .. date_to), нужны все записи, где они имеют общие даты (пересекаются, накладываются и т.п), верно?

Comment: да именно это и надо

Comment: `where (t1.end>t2.start and t1.start<t2.end) or (t1.end<t2.start and t1.start >t2.end)` Если нужны нестрогие неравенства - добавить по вкусу.